# what is the last thing you ordered takeout? -- how do you understand this sentence grammatically? I'm taking about "takeout"

Tags: predicative-complement

Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REgfziJqD14#t=1m48s (at 1 min. 48 sec., *just click the link and it will take you to the exact timing automatically*)

> What is the last thing you ordered **takeout**?

What part of speech is **takeout** in this sentence and how does it figure into the rest of the sentence grammatically? I can't really make proper sense of this sentence.

Comment: Takeout is a noun.  Food ordered by phone (or text or email) and picked up at the counter. British "takeaway".  Here it is adverbial, "in the manner of takeout".

Comment: If takeout is a noun, and a dictionary says it is, I guess I can say, "What is the last thing I watched video clip?"

Comment: Take-out has a phrasal verb lurking beneath its skin. Video-clip does not.

Comment: Did Lady Godiva ride her horse side-saddle? (Refuting my own point).

Comment: So "order takeout" is a phrasal verb with an embedded phrasal verb.

Comment: Hmm, . . . *He ordered steak; He ordered takeout; He ordered steak as takeout;* and, *"When was the last time he ordered steak/takeout?", "When was the last time he ordered steak as takeout?"*, and so, maybe, *A: "What was the last thing you ordered (as) takeout?"* --> *B: "The last thing I had ordered as takeout was steak"*.

Comment: It's adverbial in usage. I hear _what is the last thing you ordered to go_ as completely analogous, and much more common.

Comment: And . . . *He ordered [steak/takeout]; He ordered a [steak/takeout]; He ordered two [steaks/takeouts].*

Comment: I don't know if this is an AmE vs BrE thingie or not, but my AmE ear wants to hear an "as" in there: *"What is the last thing you ordered **as** takeout?"*, which would be completely unremarkable to me (that is, it would be completely acceptable and grammatical as standard English, imo). -- (Supposedly, "takeaway" is the BrE alternate to the AmE "takeout"; though I'm not so sure that they are completely the same in all senses of meanings.)

Comment: @F.E. *He ordered it hot*, *he ordered it sliced*, *I ordered it boxed*. Also consider *would you like that eat-in or take out*. Also: *that curry was take-out not eat-in*.  Lastly *a take-out* sandwich* an *eat-in meal*. It seems to me that *takeout* must be a PC in the OP's example. The OED, gives it as an adjective. I tend to think that's correct because although it isn't easily modified by an adverb, we can have *That curry was take-out* whereas we cannot have *that phone was box* or *that card was credit*. Have done a post below.  Constructive crit welcomed ;)

Comment: @F.E. It's not you. My British ear wants to hear something in between as well. It just sounds wrong. In Araucaria's examples - *would you like that eat-in or take out?* sounds equally wrong (I'd insert a "to", as would most vendors here); and *take-out sandwich* is a completely different phrase, being used as an adjective not an adverb, and thus not comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the last thing you ordered takeout?

In this sentence, **takeout** is a reduced form of the relative clause **that is takeout**. The relative clause modifies  *thing.*

In its unreduced form, the relative clause is used as follows:

What is the last thing *that is takeout* you ordered.

You can move the relative clause to the end of the sentence to highlight it:

What is the last thing you ordered *that is takeout*?

You can reduce the relative clause by removing both *that* and the verb *to be:*

Thus:

Whst is the last thing you ordered *(that is) takeout*?

Which equals:

What is the last thing you ordered *takeout*?

Note: you can also reduce the relative clause in its original position to get:

What is the last thing *(that is) takeout* you ordered?

Or:

What is the last thing *takeout* you ordered?

The above sentence is grammatical, but not necessarily idiomatic.

To get the idiomatic usage, reverse the order of *thing* and *takeout:*

What is the last *takeout thing* you ordered?

*Takeout* cannot be an adverb. It does not describe *in what manner* the person ordered.

To show this, we use a word that can only be used as an adjective, *spicy* and a word that can only be an adverb,  *abruptly.*

As an adjective, the following sentences work in the same manner that the sentences with *takeout* work:

What is the last thing *that is spicy* you ordered?

What is the last thing you ordered *that is spicy*?

What is the last thing you ordered *(that is)  spicy*?

What is the last thing you ordered *spicy*?

**Spicy** can only be an adjective, so it cannot modify *ordered.*

As with takeout, you can also reduce the relative clause in the original position:

What is the last thing *spicy* you ordered?

Which is equivalent to

What is the last spicy thing you ordered?

As mentioned, *spicy* is only an adjective, so you canot use it as an adverb. The following two sentences are **not** acceptable, because in them *spicy* fails as an adverb:

*What is the last thing you spicy ordered?
*What is the last thing you ordered spicy (adv)?

Now, a word that functions only as an adverb:

**Abrubtly** can only be used as an adverb.

So, you can have the following, with *abruptly* as an adverb modifying *ordered:*

What is the last thing you ordered *abruptly*?

However, the following does not work, because *abruptly* can **not** function as an adjective:

*What is the last thing you ordered *that is abruptly*?

The following also does not work:

*What is the last thing *(that is) abruptly* you ordered?

Nor does:

*What is the last abruptly thing you ordered?
<>
There will be sentences in which the modifier could function either as an adjective or an adverb:

As an adjective:

What is the last soup you ate cold?
What is the last soup you ate *that was cold*?
What is the last soup *that was cold* you ate?
(What is the last cold soup you ate?)

As an advervb:

What is the last soup you ate cold?

The above can mean either

What is the last soup you ate *while you were cold*?

Or:

What is the last soup you ate *in a cold manner*? (*cold* = *indifferently*)

(In the above, *cold* is a dialectal version of standard English *coldly.*)

In the following, is *damaged* an adverb or adjective:

What is the last DVD you received *damaged*?

According to the very first construction, it functions as an adjective:

What is the last DVD you received *(that was) damaged*?

But it is arguable whether *damaged* can be an adverb here. In some dialects, it could:

What is the last DVD you received *while you were damaged* (mentally damaged, for example)?

But

> What is the last thing you ordered *takeout*?

cannot be construed to mean *takeout* is an adverb.

The following do not work:

*What is the last thing you ordered *while you were takeout*?

*What is the last thing you ordered *in a takeout manner*?

We are left with

What is the last thing you ordered *takeout*?

With *takeout* functioning as an adjective in a reduced relative clause, in the same manner as:

What is the last thing you ordered *to go*?

What is the last thing you ordered *(that is)  to go*?

What is the last thing *(that is) to go* you ordered?

What is the last "to go" thing you ordered?

Comment: *What was the last thing you ordered curry?* sound very bad. Whereas *what was the last thing you ordered which was curry* seems fine. In general this type of relative clause reduction doesn't seem felicitous: *I met a man French*, *I met a man lawyer* both seem pretty bad to me ... *What was the last thing you ordered in a a takeout manner* in contrast seems perfectly acceptable to me ...

Comment: @Araucaria In my idiolect, I can consider 'curry'  only as a noun. Therefore, yes, *What is the last thing you ordered curry* is ungrammatical. Also, to me, curry is a noun in *What was the last thing you ordered that was curry*. Which is equivalent to *What is the last curry you ordered that was curry.* Also, if *What is the last thing you ordered in a takeout manner* is fine for you... What about the following:

Comment: @Araucaria (cont) *What is the last thing you ordered in an online manner?* and *What is the last thing you received in a damaged manner?* To me, *What is the last thing you ordered online*, online is not an adverb. Or is it?

Comment: It would be a preposition, I reckon. :)

Answer (score 5):

Takeout is used in a strange way here, in a way that you don't hear many other nouns used. This is referring to "takout-style". This sentence is basically asking "What is the last thing you ordered as a takeaway". Please note that (although I can not speak from an American point of view as I am English) I don't think this would be classed as grammatically correct.

Also note that I wouldn't recommend using this sort of structure, even as a native speaker I would probably not use this though that may be because I am not American. Off the top of my head, I can't think of another word that would make sense in the position of takeout.

So like I said, personally I wouldn't even consider this sentence particularly correct I think it is more likely just idiomatic American. If you are looking for the best grammatical explanation though, takeout is an adverb here.

Comment: I wouldn't want to get bogged down in *grammatical/ungrammatical* here, but this "ad-hoc adverbial" usage is definitely "non-standard" (as opposed to, say, *"What is the last thing you ordered **by phone**?"*).

Comment: But it is idiomatic in American English.

Comment: So, basically I can understand this usage as follows: what is the last thing you ordered "in the takeout manner". Does that sound to you guys like a possible understanding?

Comment: @CookieMonster That is definitely a correct understanding!

Comment: Just dawned on me. Could this be something along the lines of "what is the last thing you ordered online?"?

Comment: @CookieMonster I think saying online would imply you had ordered something other the food such as books, dvds or other items. In most cases, takeaways are not ordered online although this is something that is becoming more common.

Comment: Yes, online would be analogous. Takeout here is adverbial, and a somewhat unusual idiom (its meaning is clear, and I could imagine using the phrase, but it does sound a bit odd). The online example is much more common.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the last thing you ordered takeout?

The Oxford English Dictionary dives the following description for the adjective *take-out*:

> - 2. Of, pertaining to, or characterized by the sale of prepared food for consumption elsewhere. Cf. take-away n. 2   orig. U.S.

It is generally not a good idea to look in dictionaries for parts of speech. However, we can see that *take-out* is definitely used to modify nouns -  especially nouns indicating types of food or drink:

- I ordered a take-out sandwich.
- Take-out food is not good for your health, but it's good for your free time.

It's possible that *take-out* is an adjective here, but it also looks like a noun. However, notice that usually if we have a noun which modifies another noun, it must come directly before the noun:

- A phone box.
- A credit card.

We cannot use these nouns as predicative complements, complements which tell us about the subject. For example:

- *That box was phone. (wrong)
- *Was that card credit? (wrong)

However, we can do this with the word *take-out*:

- That curry was take-out.
- Is that eat-in or take-out?

So, in fact, it seems *take-out* is an adjectie, not a noun according to this data.

In the sentence:

- What is the last thing you ordered takeout?

... the word *take-out* is a complement of the verb *ORDER*. The verb *ORDER* can take two complements. The first complement is the direct object. In the sentences below, the direct objects are *the coffee* and *the bread*:

- I ordered the coffee hot.
- I ordered the bread in slices.

In these sentences, the verb *ORDER* has a second complement - a *predicative complement*. This complement describes the direct object. The predicative complements are *hot* and *in slices*. The adjective *hot* describes the coffee. The phrase *in slices* describes the bread.

In the Original Poster's example, the predicative complement, the adjective (-or perhaps noun) *take-out*, describes the thing you bought. It occurs in the relative clause:

- [you bought ____ take-out]

The direct object in that clause is a gap. It's antecedent is the word *thing*. We understand the noun phrase like this:

- thing [you bought (it) take-out].

So we understand *take-out* as describing the thing that you bought.

Hope this is helpful!

**Oxford English Dictionary Reference**

"ˈtake-out, adj. and n." OED Online. Oxford University Press, September 2014. Web. 25 November 2014.

Comment: Nice answer! I think you nailed the crux of the problem nicely. Two minor things I'd like to note: a) I avoided saying that *take-out* is an adjective because most dictionaries usually define these adj.-n. as adj. explicitly. I couldn't find any ref. saying that. (It looks like an adjective; I was told it's adj. And finally you found it in OED. Nice!); b) The reader might apply the test in this answer and come up with "What's the last dish you ordered seafood?" because "That dish was seafood" is grammatical. It's a small thing that I don't have any good explanation yet. Great answer, anyway.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Nice point. I think the difference is that *seafood* in *that dish is seafood* is a specifying use of *BE* where as in *that curry was takeout* the likely reading is ascriptive. So the ascriptive use gives us a quality of the food. The specifying tells us what it actually was. Same difference between, *it was meat* and *it was tasty* - I think ;)

Comment: *"We cannot use these nouns as predicative complements, complements which tell us about the subject."* <== Consider: "That curry was dinner/takeout". (Also, *CGEL* pg. 409, [19.i] *Henry became treasurer*.) I glanced at one cheap dictionary, and it only has "takeout" as a noun; its two examples are *"let’s just order takeout", "takeout pizza"*. -- It had seemed, when I had looked at this OP's question before, that at first blush that considering only a noun "takeout" might be okay. I haven't had any coffee yet, so I don't know if you've yet provided definite proof for need of an adjective. :)

Comment: Yes, I too had thought that one strong possibility was that "takeout" might be a PC in the OP's example (though as a noun PC). As your examples with the gap are showing, the verb "bought" can take one or two complements ("You bought takeout", "You bought steak", "You bought steak as takeout"), where "as" is the marker for an oblique PC. In the OP's example, the "as" might be obligatory (according to my ear) to indicate that there is a direct object gap; though, I'm not completely sure if my reasoning is correct here since there are some similar types of fronting that don't require it. :)

Comment: Actually, I'm now thinking that a non-fronted version without "as" might actually be using the first noun as a modifier for the second noun. E.g. *"You bought [steak takeout]"* is a kind of takeout, which would be similar in structure as *"takeout pizza"* (which is a single NP).

Comment: @F.E. The *these* there was meant to mean the nouns we use to modify a noun, *usually* can't be used as predicative complements of those same nouns. So *that curry was dinner* might be an exception but only if we can say *the curry dinner*  (actually, that sounds ok to me). Henry doesn't seem modifiable to me apart from apositively. However, I'm slightly less than 50% on whether *take-out* is an adjective ...

Comment: I've found some related stuff in the 2002 *CGEL*. For "take-away" (the BrE equivalent for "takeout", supposedly), as a verb-centered compound noun, on pages 1646-7 [4.ii]. (Also barely mentioned on page 1654-5 [20].)

Answer (score 1):

As some others have noted, this is a bit of a strange phrase.

It means: "What was the type of food that you have most recently purchased takeout-style?"
Takeout is a term for when you order food from a restaurant but do not eat it there. Another term for this is carryout or "to go". For example, if you were ordering something you might be asked, "Is this for here or to go?"

Grammatically, in this sentence:

> What is the last thing you ordered takeout?

"takeout" is an adjective which modifies "thing". I think this is referred to as a predicate adjective.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the natives opine that this is a bit of strange usage of the noun *takeout*. Looking at the structure, even I too find it out of the *general use* of the word. However, I'm not a native speaker, but can find appropriate references that help understand that phrase.

> [takeout (n)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/TAKEOUT) - ***Prepared food*** that is intended to be eaten off of the premises

The synonym described is *takeout food*.

Said this, the closest way we can interpret this sentence

> what is the last thing you ordered ***takeout?***

...is the speaker is asking about the last *takeout food* the listener has ordered.